# WPF SelectedItem property in nested DataGrid in UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, user-controls, selecteditem

I have `UserControl`, lets call it as `CustomDataGrid`, that contains `DataGrid`. Remained content doesn't matter. `SelectedItem` property of `DataGrid` must be `SelectedItem` property of `CustomDataGrid`. And I wanna be able to use `Binding` with this property, cause I use `MVVM` pattern. So I have to declare `SelectedItem` as `DependencyProperty` in `CustomDataGrid`. But I have no ideas haw can I make it properly...

This is how `DepedencyProperty`-s is declared usually:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItem", typeof(Object), typeof(CustomDataGrid),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Object), SelectedItemPropertyCallback)
        {
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true, 
            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        });

// Optionally
private static void SelectedItemPropertyCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // dataGrid - `DataGrid` nested in `UserControl` 
    ((CustomDataGrid)obj).dataGrid.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
}

// Obviously, it has no any link with nested `dataGrid`. This is the problem.  
public Object SelectedItem
{

    get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
```

So, how can I declare `SelectedItem` property correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leverage the binding framework for wiring such properties from underlying objects to outer containers

example assuming `CustomDataGrid` as `UserControl`

```cs
        class CustomDataGrid : UserControl
        {
            public CustomDataGrid()
            {
                Binding b = new Binding("SelectedItem");
                b.Source = this;
                b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                dataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.SelectedItemProperty, b);
            }

            public object SelectedItem
            {
                get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
                set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
            }

            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(CustomDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        }
```

I have created a property called `SelectedItem` in `CustomDataGrid` and set a two way binding to `SelectedItem` of the actual `dataGrid` inside.

so this will wire up these properties and will propagate any changes to and fro.

Comment: Not acceptable for me to hardcode `Binding` in constructor. I found this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381560/wpf-usercontrol-selecteditem-of-a-usercontrol-datagrid-to-bind-to-a-itemsource. It works, but not enough. What if I want to set `SelectedItem` from outer code? How value will pass to `dataGrid`?

Comment: if you set SelectedItem from the outer code, binding will push the value to datagrid's SelectedItem. just give it a try. secondly writing any such code is a kind of hardcoding, no matter you do in constructor, in property setter, property changed events or any other event handlers. otherwise you can combine your solution with the one in the link and make a complete wiring of properties.

Comment: You right, nice solution, it works even better then in link I posted

Answer (score 2):

**XAML solution!**

Use this DependencyProperty:

```
public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}  

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(CustomDataGrid ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
{
    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
    DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
});
```

Then make your outer CustomDataGrid UserControl XAML look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomDataGrid">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CustomDataGrid}}}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CustomDataGrid}}}">

    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

You can then use the CustomDataGrid control the same way as the DataGrid control when binding ItemsSource and SelectedItem to your view model.

Comment: . @monstr This works beautifully and IMO is cleaner, thank you bugged87!