# How can I pass data from usercontrol to another usercontrol using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

For example I have a mainwindow that has a frame on it which binds to a model of all user controls that I have.

Example: (Basic Personal Information)

I have a usercontrol or (view-1) that display single person from my personalInformation database.

and I also have a usercontrol or (view-2) that display all the list of person in my database.

the question is how can I get the ID of single person from (view-2) to (view-1) as they are different usercontrol and different viewmodel as well.

what is the best approach to this kind of scenario? TIA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you came across dependency injection and event aggregator?

Comment: Do you really need to have two different ViewModel classes? From the information in your question I would also see it fit to have one ViewModel containing a property to have a list of persons and a property for the selected person. Both Views could use the same ViewModel instance.

Comment: Just to have a clean separation of viewmodel for each views. I'm just thinking that having a single viewmodel for each views would be a great way when it comes to source code management, easy to read and maintain. just a thought. what do you think?

Comment: You are correct if you have commands that are specific for the one or the other view and are handled in the ViewModel. In that case maybe delegate the responsibility of keeping track of the selected person to the model. And inject the same model into the ViewModel classes. This could be done from the ViewModel which is serving the MainWindow.

Comment: can I access the model of my MainWindowViewModel from my usercontrol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A

The `Usercontrols` are some elements to be part of your `Window`, then the `Window` can be the suitable connector between your `UserControls`. you can approach this scenario like this:

1. **`WindowA`**
2. **`UserControlPersonList`**

   - Include `SelectedPersion` [Dependency Property](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html). `SelectedPerson` type is a `model class` or `viewmodel class`
3. **`UserControlPerson`**

Now, inside WindowA.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <userControls:UserControlPersonList x:Name="PersonListControl"/>

    <userControls:UserControlPerson DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PersonListControl, Path=SelectedPerson}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The result can be something like this (a master-detail view):

[image]

You need fill `SelectedPerson` dependency property of `UserControlPersonList` when you select a person. To perform this you can use `Command` and change `SelectedPerson` property in `PersonListViewModel` and bind `SelectedPerson` dependency property in `UserControlPersonList` to it *OR* do this in your `UserControlPersonList` level like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381560/wpf-usercontrol-selecteditem-of-a-usercontrol-datagrid-to-bind-to-a-itemsource).

---

### B

But if you want some global changed in your `UserControls` in different `Windows` you can hold the `PersonListViewModel` in a static property that is accessible in all of your `Windows` and `Usercontrols` of your program then create an `event` in it named `SelectedPersionChanged`. Now in your `UserControls` you can subscribe an `EventHandler` to `SelectedPersionChanged` and change your `DataContext`.
But you *MUST* unsubscribe your `EventHandler` from `SelectedPersionChanged` when you did not need to that `UserControl` anymore to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation. By the way is this the traditional approach?

Comment: First way (A) is a good, easy and safe approach. your codes are minimal and if you want you can hold the selected person in your ViewModel... sometimes its useful. The second way (B) is for a specific mode and i recommend you to use first way if your application need not real-time changes in some user controls in different windows.

Comment: Thanks sir RAM.. but how can I manage the navigation of controls? I mean how can I tell to the mainwindow to display the list or to display the selected person? TIA

Comment: how about global instance? creating viewmodel resources in application level?

Comment: This can do in different ways, you can create a `master-detail` view like the image i added to the answer. Or you can create a `PersionDetail Window` and try open it by passing the `SelectedPersion` info of `PersionList` usercontrol to its constractor. To impelement this scenario you need add an event in your `PersonList` usercontrol named `SelectedPersonChanged` like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447940/how-to-create-user-define-new-event-for-user-control-in-wpf-one-small-example).

Comment: No, i think the B way is last way and it is useful in another mods. It is not good idea to use static properties to approach simple scenarios like which you want. You should pass data (SelecterPerson object) between `Usercontrols` or `Windows` similar to what I've described in my previous comment.

Comment: But I rendered the user control programmatically, like what I said the frame is bounded to the model of all usercontrol.. I created a model that has a list of all usercontrols object and its name.. then calling the method from model to change the current object(usercontrol) to change the current usercontrol displayed in the mainwindow..

Comment: I don't know why you keep a list of usercontrol objects and their names in a model!!! I wrote a standard way to play with your user controls. if you have additional question please write a new question and insert your classes and their scenario completely there.